# CSS_Select pseudo-elements that match portions of strings inside attribute values

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

How can I select markers in CSS that match e.g. only pdf filetype from the `href` attribute?

```css
a[href$=".pdf"]::before {
  background-image: url(https://web-dev.imgix.net/image/VbAJIREinuYvovrBzzvEyZOpw5w1/fc7bLiJYf5US6QxTOKsF.png);
}

a[href$=".jpg"]::before,
a[href$=".png"]::before {
  background-image: url(https://web-dev.imgix.net/image/VbAJIREinuYvovrBzzvEyZOpw5w1/N79qCc0c06217YT4ofYM.png);
}


a::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-inline-end: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article class="flow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="my-image.jpg">An example image</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="my-document.pdf">An example document</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="my-document.png">Another example document</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```

I've tried this:

```
ul li::marker a[href$=".pdf"]
```

this

```
 li a[href$=".pdf"]::marker
```

and this

```
li::marker a[href$=".pdf"]
```

but it didn't work

Comment: As the `::marker` pseudo-element is applied to the `<li>` element this isn't possible, as it would require style to be applied to the `<li>` element based on the attributes of a descendant. While this has been proposed in CSS, it is not yet implemented in any browser (as of writing).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this exactly as wanted as you can't go 'backwards' in CSS to influence the styling of a parent element in this way.

You can do a fiddle to make it look as though the markers are your images by placing them slightly in front of the links, positioned absolutely in relation to their parent li element:

```css
a[href$=".pdf"]::before {
  background-image: url(https://web-dev.imgix.net/image/VbAJIREinuYvovrBzzvEyZOpw5w1/fc7bLiJYf5US6QxTOKsF.png);
}

a[href$=".jpg"]::before,
a[href$=".png"]::before {
  background-image: url(https://web-dev.imgix.net/image/VbAJIREinuYvovrBzzvEyZOpw5w1/N79qCc0c06217YT4ofYM.png);
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

a::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.5em;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-inline-end: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

::marker {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article class="flow">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="my-image.jpg">An example image</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="my-document.pdf">An example document</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="my-document.png">Another example document</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```